# SoftLayer API: What is the SoftLayer API to get a list of valid device to add subnet IP Address

Tags: php, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When ordering IP Address from  Network -->Subnets, such as 1 Static Public IP Address, there will be a list of Endpoint IP address shown under the account,  which Softlayer API method can generate that list of eligible Endpoint IP address to add the subnets on ?

Thanks.

Comment: Code! Code! Code! We want some code! Please add some :P

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the following API can give a list of valid device:
SoftLayer_Account::getSubnets